# [fragment]'s purpose is fragmented

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

[fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fragment) has ~7k questions. The tag summary isn't very encouraging, and sums up the issue pretty well:

> 'fragment' is an ambiguous tag, used to refer to numerous technologies. Prefer less ambiguous tags.

It seems to be mostly used for fragments in Android, but the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fragment/info) says to use [android-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragments) instead. The tag wiki also mentions URL fragments (`#foo`), and says they should go under [media-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-fragments), except that tag doesn't exist and links to W3C's spec instead of a tag. Another use that comes to mind is OpenGL fragments and fragment shaders.

Should we clarify this tag, burninate it, or something else?

Comment: The tag should be removed, but the question should be retag appropriately (if related to android, then change fragment to tag android-fragment)

Comment: Could a moderator or high rep user create [tag:media-fragments] as part of this retagging effort?

Comment: @tepples I think `url-fragment` would be better. Or just `url`.

Answer (score 5):

The tag now also has an explicit warning stating:

> **DO NOT USE**

In addition to the ambiguity, the tag wiki also suggests avoiding it.

Of the currently near 7000 questions, [only 396](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfragment%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) are not tagged with Android. Of those, just scrolling through quickly, I see several Android questions without the Android tag as well.

Android is the main use on this tag. The tag doesn't exclusively contain questions that need to be closed. Aside the usual closing of off-topic questions, I suggest:

- Re-tag the Android questions with [android-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-fragments) and other relevant tags, *except* when it's about OpenGL.
- Re-tag questions asking about URLs with [fragment-identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fragment-identifier)
- Re-tag WiX-related questions with [wix-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix-fragments) (doesn't currently exist).
- Re-tag OpenGL-related questions with [fragment-shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fragment-shader)
- Remove the tag from questions that i.e. ask about a "fragment of a [UI element]"
- Catch-all: If necessary (and useful - there's not really a point in creating it for one question either), create new tags for any other missed meanings. For the others, where tags would be either ambiguous, off-topic, or otherwise unnecessary, remove it.

Some of these are also outlined in the tag wiki.

Comment: OpenGL related question should be retagged with [tag:fragment-shader]; [tag:shader] is also an ambiguous tag.